# HTTPUrlConnection PUT fails to send JSON to server

Tags: android, json, rest, httpurlconnection

I have following code through which i am unable to send a json string using PUT request to my server. Server has REST api.

```
 try {


            m_url = new URL(URL);
            m_conn = (HttpURLConnection) m_url.openConnection();
            URL url = m_conn.getURL();
            Log.d("Sending to --->", url.toString());

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject jsondtObj = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject jsonitObj = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

            jsonObject.put("addr_locality_o", "White plains");
            jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
            jsondtObj.put("data", jsonArray);
            jsonitObj.put("template",jsondtObj);

            Log.d("sending JSON: " , jsonitObj.toString());
            String sessionID = m_qeeAppCtrl.getSessTok();
            Log.d("session Token: " , sessionID);


            m_conn.setDoOutput(true);
            m_conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            m_conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            m_conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", sessionID);


            OutputStream out = m_conn.getOutputStream();
            out.write(jsonitObj.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
            out.close();
            m_conn.getInputStream();

            retc = m_conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("Response : ", String.valueOf(retc));


            if (retc == 200) {
                Log.d("NO Exception: ", "");
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Exception: ", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Exception: ", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception: ", e.getMessage());
        }finally {
            return retc;
        }
```

I do not get any thing in the server logs and at the same time, I do not get any exception in the logcat window nor response code gets printed in the log file.  I looked into the other forums but even after applyinig all solutions such as UTf-8 coding , still no clue :(

Please help

Thanks

Comment: have you checked the response in browser?

Comment: You mean pasting the URL in the browser and see what happens ? Yes i get back the rest pop UP. Also i have a test client from the browser, whis is working fine with the same rest call. But with android i face this problem. I am not sure what i am missing in the header !

Comment: if response from restclient is ok..then you are probably not done the things correctly...
debug your program and find the server response code.
My final sugestion is why to go for PUT if there is POST?

Comment: i debugged it and noticed that after OutputStream out = m_conn.getOutputStream();  nothing happens, so basically there is some problem in while getting this output stream. Well I thought put is for update and post is for create. However, put can be used for both, but still PUT should be working fine even though there might be better reasons to use POST!

Comment: Ok..What is is the response code?  here
" Log.d("Response : ", String.valueOf(retc)); "

Comment: That is the problem, this log statement never gets printed. And i wonder in case of an exception why it does not prints any log statement . So i am clueless why neither an exception nor this log statement gets printed at all :(

Comment: @k2ibegin i suggest you may just go through with "volley" android library for RESTful api service with HTTP . here is link where you may find better examples : http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/  and another is http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: yes, it is in my mind. however, right now initially while my app is in beginning stages we want to not only test the android app, but the server Domino where the rest interface is. So once this is done, then we are planning to move onto the volley. Sorry, if it sounds strange but this is what i have to do :(